# RSA.SignHash SHA512 and SHA256 give the same signature length

Tags: c#, hash, cryptography, rsa

Strange, but signature array length are the same for the code:

```
using (RSA rsa = certifiateToUse.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    byte[] bytesData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] hash512 = rsa.SignHash(bytesData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
    byte[] hash256 = rsa.SignHash(bytesData, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
}
```

Both hash512 and hash256 have 512 array length. I can not find a reasonable answer to this. Maybe I'm missing something obvious? I expected it to be 512 and 256 bytes long each.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SHA-256 and SHA-512 produce 256 and 512 bit hashes, respectively.

Your RSA key is 1024 or 2048 bits, and the block size when  using it as a cipher is the same.

Since both hashes are smaller than the RSA block size, they need to be *padded* out to that size. And because they are padded, the **resulting signatures will be the same size regardless of the hash algorithm used**.

The clue here is the last parameter, which specifies the padding algorithm.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, that makes sense. After replacing 4096 certificate to 2048 which, consequently, has smaller block size, signature size changed to 256. It is strange though that SignHash takes HashAlgorithmName if it is not actually used.

Comment: The hash algorithm *is* used, and hashes of different sizes are produced. But those resulting hashes are padded out to the RSA block size  before signing.

Comment: Got it. Just checked speed of HashAlgorithmName.SHA512 vs HashAlgorithmName.SHA256 by doing 1000 operations each. Seems SHA512 is even a bit faster.

Comment: @jonathon-reinhart How would this answer change if using a Curve25519 key (ECC which are smaller) rather than large RSA keys?